# CSS dropdown menu closes up automatically in touch devices

Tags: jquery, css

My css dropdown menu works pretty fine in desktop. But in touch screen mobile and tablets, when I scroll page, the dropdown menu closes automatically. It collapses up automatically and can't be used for navigation. How can I force my dropdown menu to stay open even the page is scrolled up or down?

My code is:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav_wrapper"> <!-- NAV WRAPPER STARTS -->

    <div id="menu_icon_wrapper">
    <div id="menu_icon"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="nav_bar"> <!-- NAV BAR STARTS -->

    <ul id="nav"> <!-- NAV STARTS -->
    <li><a href="providers">Providers</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="actrix.html">Actrix</a></li>
            <li><a href="digital-island.html">Digital Island</a></li>
            <li><a href="farmside.html">Farmside</a></li>
            <li><a href="flip.html">Flip</a></li>
            <li><a href="inspire.html">Inspire</a></li>
            <li><a href="maxnet.html">Maxnet</a></li>
            <li><a href="orcon.html">Orcon</a></li>
            <li><a href="slingshot.html">Slingshot</a></li>
            <li><a href="telecom.html">Telecom</a></li>
            <li><a href="telstraclear.html">TelstraClear</a></li>
            <li><a href="vodafone.html">Vodafone</a></li>
            <li><a href="woosh.html">Woosh</a></li>
            <li><a href="xnet.html">Xnet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="compare">Compare</a></li>
    <li><a href="reviews">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- NAV ENDS -->

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    </div> <!-- NAV BAR ENDS -->

</div> <!-- NAV WRAPPER ENDS -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu_icon_wrapper
{
    display:none; /* hide menu icon initially */
}

#menu_icon
{
    background-image:url('../images/menu-icon.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-21px;
    right:-1px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#nav_bar ul li a
{
    background-color:#F29E33;
    border-top:1px solid #dd7d06;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:6px 12px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    outline:none;
    text-align:left;
}

#nav_bar ul li a:hover,
#nav_bar ul li a.active
{
    background-color:#dd7d06;
}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a
{
    text-indent:25px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
/* toggle nav */
$("#menu_icon").on("click", function(){
    $("ul#nav").slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: How are we meant to help without seeing something? I don't have a clue how you're opening/closing the menu and what events are handled. My best guess (and it really is a guess) is that the 'touchdown' of somewhere other than the menu (i.e. to scroll) is calling the close function. But this is possibly entirely irrelevant, post an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess this caused due the fact that your are touching outside the menu in order to scroll.
Therefore leaving focus and or hover of the menu.